# Inbox does not use DNS, but the IP 69.59.197.29

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, global-inbox

I use the [RequestPolicy plugin for FireFox](https://www.requestpolicy.com/) and noticed that the global inbox/notifications currently doesn't work (at least not here in Germany): It shows the new message indication, but the popup does not show. The reason seems to be some broken DNS: SX asks for access to the IP 69.59.197.29. If I enable access to that IP with RequestPolicy, the inbox works.

Comment: This _just_ started happening? E.g. could be an artifact of the fail over to the Oregon DC?

Comment: @TimPost♦: It worked yesterday evening in Germany, so 10h before.

Comment: This IP is used for the web sockets connection, the actual request URL is `ws://69.59.197.29/` however the notifications take data from different place. Weird..

Comment: Saw this too, the proxy here appears to choke on websockets, so I had an exception in for the `sockets.ny.stackexchange.com` url. Now it's hitting this IP directly, for some reason.

Comment: Just tried this, and had the same issue. Added an exception for the IP address, then it worked just fine.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: Yeah, but it shouldn't use the IP, but some name.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I agree. Just noting that the issue isn't local to you - I'd guess that anyone using RequestPolicy will have the same problem.

Comment: According to the `whois` that IP belongs to a company in Oregon. This might be a fast-fired-solution due to Sandy hitting NY. Joel said earlier that they'd switch all services from NY to OR.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby this is clearly a Firefox issue, as it's tied to one of its plugins. Why did you remove the tag?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: This is not caused by the plugin.

Comment: You mean that it always fail, also with other browsers?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I picked it up as "Inbox stopped working because my Plugin is blocking all direct IP requests...why is the Inbox directly querying an IP instead of a name?"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Most likely. I can only test with FF: Firebug shows access to that IP.

Comment: Yep, unrelated to firefox -- the plugin part just makes it obvious that the website is sending requests directly to an IP address.  Same thing happened to me, and I found this post via searching for the IP address. (69.59.197.29)

Comment: Saw the same thing. (I love RequestPolicy.) It never occurred to me it might be something to do with a hurricane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a temporary solution for websockets as part of the Oregon failover due to the hurricane that hit NYC.

We'll eventually start routing by a proper domain again, either when we return to our NY data center or after we've finished settling into Oregon.

Comment: Why are you using the IP for `sockets.ny.stackexchange.com` instead of the name?